# How to make a slideshow with Javascript to fit for mobile devices using media queries

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, media-queries

I am using the 1140 grid and I have a slideshow I made with Javascript that switches between images every 2.5 seconds. But I am not sure on how to shrink down my slideshow so that it will fit for mobile devices. I've tried with the media queries to shrink it down but nothing works. Any idea on how to do this?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="twelvecol last">
      <div class="slideshow">
        <canvas id='showCanvas' width='1022' height='397'>
        Canvas Not Supported
        </canvas>
        <div class="caption">
          <p id="tagLine">Image Number</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

enter code here

Comment: And what in consternation is "quires"?

Comment: whoops spelling mistake media "queries"

Comment: Can you provide a working example, perhaps in http://jsfiddle.net/, so others can see the problem and attempt to fix it? And please share your javascript you are using to make the slideshow.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kQpSC/3/ heres all of my code

Comment: The slideshow is not working in your example. Can you show us a working example please? It does not have to be in jsFiddle. It can be an upload of your site if you prefer. If you are going to use jsFiddle it would be more helpful to put up just enough code to show the problem. Not all of your code. And make sure it is working.